# Safari RegEx lookbehind alternative

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to be able to highlight keywords inside an HTML string

I have a keywords array that can contain keywords like `storage box` `kitchen storage box` `kitchen organiser`.
Also there is a content where i need to highlight these keywords.

As you can see the storage box is repeated in 2 keywords and i don't want to highlight `storage box` if `kitchen storage box` is already highlighted. So first, i ordered the keywords by max length so i get to highlight the bigger ones first and then the smaller ones.

I am using the following code to replace each found keyword with `<mark>{keyword}</mark>`

```
            _.each(this.keywords, keyword => {

                keyword.value = this.replaceNbsps(keyword.value)

                // find the keyword but do not take already highlighted elements into consideration
                // for this we use negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to not include keywords that are preceded with <mark> and succeeded with </mark>
                let regex = new RegExp(`((?<=\\s|^|\\W)(?<!<mark class="keyword_\\d">)${this.escapeRegExp(keyword.value)}(?!<\/mark>)(?=\\s|$|\\W))`, 'guim')

                highlightedContent = highlightedContent.replace(regex, `<mark class="keyword_${keyword.index}">$&</mark>`)
            });
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this without using negative lookbehind and negative lookahead in order for it to work also in Safari?

Comment: `(?<=\\s|^|\\W)` = `(?!\\B\\w)`. You can also replace `(?=\\s|$|\\W)` with `(?!\\w)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
let regex = new RegExp(
  `(<mark class="keyword_\\d">)?(?!\\B\\w)${this.escapeRegExp(keyword.value)}(?!</mark>)(?!\\w)`,
  'guim')
highlightedContent = highlightedContent.replace(regex, (match, gr1) => 
  gr1 ? match : `<mark class="keyword_${keyword.index}">${match}</mark>`)
```